# How to send request to a method of Web Service from Postman?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, postman, asmx

I have an ASMX service, which has the below method. I want to debug this method, so I have put a breakpoint on it. But I am not able to send a request to it successfully, It gives a 404 error.

```
[WebMethod]
public void RequestNotification()
{
```

I have tried these options so far.

[image]

Page screenshots for reference.

[image]
[image]

This is how I am calling from the C# code, and this is also not hitting the breakpoint on the method `RequestNotification` of service. and it's not giving any exceptions also in the C# code.

```
MyService myService= new MyService ();
myService.RequestNotification();
```

Update: I have tried as described in the below answer, I am still getting 404.

Please find below the request screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using POST call from Postman with XML Body

Demo code.
I will show this [Calculator SOAP service](http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx) for `Add` operation.

[image]

[image]

POST URL

```
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
```

In body with `XML` ray selection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>100</intA>
      <intB>200</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[image]

[image]

I got response this from service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <AddResult>300</AddResult>
        </AddResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you click `code` button from Postman, you can get the `curl` command too.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' \
--header 'SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/Add' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <intA>100</intA>
      <intB>200</intB>
    </Add>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bench, I have tried as described by you, but still getting the same error. I have updated my question with the Postman request, what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure but you make a wrong two items, first POST URL, it's response HTML means not correct URL. You needs to find a matched URL from your C# code. Second, `SOAPAction` is not your SOAP's operation. That is calculator's operation. it should be your notification operation. But I have no experience to implement SOAP by C#.

Comment: I don't think the problem is not related to C# , I am trying to hit URL from Postman like you

Comment: You are right, I am able to solve the issue by changing the URL and SOAPAction. I have posted the request and response in the answer

Comment: I am happy to hear addressed your problem!

Comment: One more upvote for you :)

Comment: I happy again that you makes me over 2K score in Today.

Comment: Great, enjoy your journey

Answer (score 1):

@Bench Vue's answer has helped me in solving the issue.  I am able to solve the issue with the below request.

**Request and Response**:

[image]

[image]